# Can I rescale an image without using an imaging library?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x

I have been looking now for a few hours and I can't find and answer to if can I rescale a image without using a imaging library. I am using python 3 don't really know if that matters. Thank you

Comment: Why would you not want to use an imaging library?

Comment: You're looking for something in the standard library? You could use command line tools otherwise like http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php.

Comment: Of course you can, it's just data.

Comment: The principles of rescaling are actually very simple - for each pixel of the output image, determine its location in the input image and use interpolation or filtering to get the pixel value. Doing it in pure Python will be abysmally slow though.

Comment: I am not sure about what is your use case. But if you want to rescale images and don't want to bother about imaging libraries, then you can use cloud based image resizing services like [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io)

Would be great if you could explain more about your use case.

Comment: Unless your image data is stored in a simple, uncompressed format (like PPM or BMP) then it will be very difficult to do anything without using some external tools. The loading is the hard part, scaling is fairly straight forward once the image is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Images has so many formats, compressed, uncompressed, black & white or colored, they may be flat or layered, the may be constructed as raster or vector ones, so the answer is generally **NO**.